# geLocations() always returns null

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I'm getting the locations either from GPS or Network. The problem is that i have tested it on htc desire hd and it worked perfectly fine, but now i started testing on other devices in samsung galaxy locations are always null.

Here is my code for getting locations

```
  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if( currentLocation == null){
    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the cellphone have other provider? Besides there seems to be a memory leak for the location manager on Samsung Galaxy. Just google it.

Comment: yes the device also using network provider at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any of the API examples for GPS to work? I presume some phones will only give the app the last known location if the app has already set up a location listener, and waited for the first location to arrive. Your code wouldn't do this.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private LocationManager lm;
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        startLocating();
    }
    private void startLocating(){
        lm.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 10, this);  
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        /*
         * put your code here
         */
    }
    @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}
    @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register a listener for location changes. Add something like the following:

```
 LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    doSomethingWithLocation();
                }
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }
        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
```

Make sure you add the proper wait time when requesting location updates. With a zero instead of the 1000, the system will not have enough time to get the new location.

A call to getLastKnownLocation() after running the above code should remove your null problem.